# Fetching the "timeZoneName" by Passing "timeZoneId" from google map API

Tags: api, google-maps, timezone, timezone-offset, google-maps-timezone

Please refer this [Link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/intro)

This API Call passes the location in request, and get the response with the details in JSON/XML

eg : **Request**

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=39.6034810,-119.6822510&timestamp=1331161200&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

**Response**

`{
   "dstOffset" : 0,
   "rawOffset" : -28800,
   "status" : "OK",
   "timeZoneId" : "America/Los_Angeles",
   "timeZoneName" : "Pacific Standard Time"
}`

I want to pass the "timeZoneId" in request Parameter and and fetch "timeZoneName" and if possible other details in Output.

Something like this :

**Request** :

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?timeZoneId=America/Los_Angeles,-119.6822510&timestamp=1331161200&key="Your Api Key"
```

**Response**

```
{
   "dstOffset" : 0,
   "rawOffset" : -28800,
   "timeZoneName" : "Pacific Standard Time"
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Currently, Google Maps API doesn't have such option. Probably you can create a feature request in public [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=apitype%3ATimeZoneAPI&sort=-stars&colspec=ID+Type+Status+Introduced+Fixed+Summary+Internal+Stars&cells=tiles).

Comment: Thanks for Confirming @xomena :) Is there any other way to achieve the same apart from google maps api.

Comment: What language are you using?  You don't need to go back to google for this.  For example, if you're using .net, you can use [this library](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneNames).  There are others for other languages as well.

Comment: I want it in Perl or javascript. Is there any API call to Dot Net Library?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to achieve it for now using google map api's.

A request for new feature enhancement has been raised here

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10521&thanks=10521&ts=1474285846